# Binding to multiple button clicks

Tags: hammerspoon

To bind to the <kbd>1</kbd> key I use:

```
hs.hotkey.bind(hyper, '1'
```

How to bind to multiple presses of <kbd>1</kbd> key? Something like:

```
hs.hotkey.bind(hyper, '1+1'
```

Reading [the documentation](http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.hotkey.html), this functionality is not mentioned.

By multiple presses I mean press `1` twice to run some code and press `1` three times to run a separate piece of code.

Comment: How would you distinguish between one ` and two presses?

Comment: @AndrewLi I've updated question, hope this makes it clearer

Comment: Sure but how will the computer distinguish between one 1 press and three presses? How does the computer know if I'm going to press 1 once or two more times?

Comment: @AndrewLi sorry I don't understand , "how will the computer distinguish between one 1 press and three presses" in same way the computer understand difference between single click, double click or 3 mouse click...

Comment: @AndrewLi ok, then maybe I should just bind to 1 and 2 keys pressed at same time, is this hacky ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to implement this yourself. Here's a basic summary of how to accomplish this:

1. Start a timer from zero, and set a flag for the first press initially to false, which indicates the first press has not happened yet
2. Observe and watch keypresses with `hs.eventtap`, specifically `hs.eventtap.event.types.keyPress`
3. When the event (`keyPress`) happens, check if the key pressed was the correct key
4. If it was the right key, check if it's the second press and if it was in time, if it wasn't in time *or* was not the second press then set the timer to the current time and first flag to true
5. If it was the second press *and* was in time, then execute our handler and reset timer and first flag
6. If it wasn't the right key then reset the timer and first flag

Translated into code, this is what is could look like (I'm not a Lua expert). Note that the flags could be implemented as booleans here, or as an internal table holding keypresses so far which you could check:

```lua
local timer = require("hs.timer")
local eventtap = require("hs.eventtap") 
local keycodes = require("hs.keycodes")
local events = eventtap.event.types --all the event types

timeFrame = 1 --this is the timeframe in which the second press should occur, in seconds
key = 50 --the specific keycode we're detecting, in this case, 50

--print(keycodes.map["`"]) you can look up the certain keycode by accessing the map

function twoHandler()
    hs.alert("Pressed ` twice!") --the handler for the double press
end

function correctKeyChecker(event) --keypress validator, checks if the keycode matches the key we're trying to detect
    local keyCode = event:getKeyCode()
    return keyCode == key --return if keyCode is key
end

function inTime(time) --checks if the second press was in time
    return timer.secondsSinceEpoch() - time < timeFrame --if the time passed from the first press to the second was less than the timeframe, then it was in time
end

local pressTime, firstDown = 0, false --pressTime was the time the first press occurred which is set to 0, and firstDown indicates if the first press has occurred or not

eventtap.new({ events.keyDown }, function(event) --watch the keyDown event, trigger the function every time there is a keydown
    if correctKeyChecker(event) then --if correct key
        if firstDown and inTime(pressTime) then --if first press already happened and the second was in time
            twoHandler() --execute the handler
        elseif not firstDown or inTime(pressTime) then --if the first press has not happened or the second wasn't in time
            pressTime, firstDown = timer.secondsSinceEpoch(), true --set first press time to now and first press to true
            return false --stop prematurely
        end
    end
    pressTime, firstDown = 0, false --if it reaches here that means the double tap was successful or the key was incorrect, thus reset timer and flag
    return false --keeps the event propogating
end):start() --start our watcher
```

I've commented the code line-by-line for a better understanding. If you want to detect 3 or 4 or some other arbitrary N number of presses, just set flags for N - 1 presses and add a few checks, but it's unusual to have key combinations that take more than 2 successive presses. It does seem a little verbose, but AFAIK this is how you do it. To avoid duplicate code and boilerplate, try putting this in a class-like structure or a module so that you can reuse code.

As for executing a different handler for 2 successive presses, or 3 successive presses, that would be a little more hacky since you would have to wait the whole timeframe before knowing if the user will press again to know which handler to execute. That would cause a slight delay and a bad user experience, I would suggest against that, though you could probably implement that by refactoring the code and doing some more checks such as if it's the timeframe and the first flag was triggered, then execute the handler for one press.

Answer (score 1):

You can not bind all keys or multiple keys with bind. Instead you can use this function: http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html#keyStroke

So the most straight forward programming language agnostic approach is as follows:

1. Call your function for any key stroke.
2. Within the function keep a static instance variable that will keep previous key strokes.
3. As the first task of your function append the new coming character to that variable.
4. Check the last 3 characters if they are the desired "11" string.

Extra for extreme conditions:

5. If the variable length pass a certain point reduce it to length 1 so that it does not keep unnecessary place in memory.

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution for n keypresses

Very late to the party but there's little to no info on this, so I thought I should really put this here considering this is one of the only search results for this.

My solution is a bit more elegant then some others (in my opinion); there are definitely some things that could be improved about it but I'm not really familiar enough with Lua or Hammerspoon to fix them.

It should work to assign a shortcut to as many consecutive keypresses as you want.

Read the code comments for an explanation of how it works. I've tried to be as detailed as possible, in an effort to make it more beginner friendly for those that don't know much about coding and those that aren't that familiar with Lua or Hammerspoon (like me).

```lua
require("hs.timer") -- Load timer module, used for timing

keyDownCount = 0 -- Keypress counter, used later in the program to store the number of times the key has been pressed
keyMultipressGapTime = 0.3 -- Max time between consecutive keypresses, used to determine when the user has stopped pressing the key
keyMaxPressCount = 3 -- Max number of key presses
testKeyCode = 18 -- Key code to bind shortcut to (in this case the 1 key)

-- READ CheckKeyDownCount FUNCTION CODE (BELOW) FIRST
-- Function to press a key with code
-- This isn't completely intuitive so I'm including it
-- Im sure there's a better way of doing this but this is what I figured out
function PressKey(keyCode) 
    keyDown = hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(keyCode, true) -- Create new keydown event using the keycode passed in the keycode argument
    keyDown:setProperty(hs.eventtap.event.properties.eventSourceUserData, 1) -- Sets user data byte of keydown event to 1, used later to prevent keydown event handler from self triggering
    keyDown:post() -- Fire keydown event
    hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(keyCode, false):post() -- Create and fire keyup event using the keycode passed in the keycode argument
end

-- READ EVENT HANDLER CODE (BELOW) FIRST
-- Function to check the number of times the key was pressed and act accordingly
-- Pretty self explanatory
function CheckKeyDownCount()
    CheckKeyDownCountTimer:stop() -- Stops keydown timer so it doesn't repeat
    -- There may be a better way of doing this but I can't find a way to creating and restarting a non repeating timer without creating a whole new timer object every time

    if keyDownCount == 1 then -- Perform action based on number of keypresses
        hs.alert("Pressed once")
        PressKey(testKeyCode)
    elseif keyDownCount == 2 then
        hs.alert("Pressed twice")
    elseif keyDownCount == 3 then
        hs.alert("Pressed thrice")
    end
    
    keyDownCount = 0 -- Reset keypress counter
end

CheckKeyDownCountTimer = hs.timer.new(keyMultipressGapTime, CheckKeyDownCount) -- Creates timer for determining when the user has stopped pressing the key
-- Time interval is set to the max time between consecutive keypresses
-- Runs the CheckKeyDownCount function at end of time interval
-- IMPORTANT: Time interval automatically resets when timer is stopped and started

-- Creates keydown event handler
-- FOR BEGINNERS: An event handler is a routine that runs when triggered by an event (kind of like an interrupt if you know what that is), normally they call a function, like below
-- FOR BEGINNERS CONTINUED: The timer above is also an event handler of sorts, with the event being the end of the time interval, event handlers are very useful because they allow asynchronous code execution
-- FOR BEGINNERS CONTINUED: In this case asynchronous code execution means that the program will continue executing until an event needs to be handled, the program will then stop where it is, handel the event, and then jump back to where it left off
multipressBtnShortcuts = hs.eventtap.new({hs.eventtap.event.types.keyDown}, function(event) 
    -- FOR BEGINNERS: "function(event)" creates anonymous function containing the below code and passes it the keydown event as an object called "event" (Just makes the code neater, you could use a separate function if you want)
    -- FOR BEGINNERS CONTINUED: An anonymous function is just a function without an identifier (name), instead they're objects and often behave kinda like variables (look this up, it's kinda hard to explain and not relevant here)
    -- RANDOM NOTE: Also turns out all functions in lua are anonymous which is pretty interesting, the interpreter just converts the structure "function foo(x) return 2*x end" into "foo = function (x) return 2*x end" 
    
    if event:getKeyCode() == testKeyCode and event:getProperty(hs.eventtap.event.properties.eventSourceUserData) == 0 then -- Check if keycode is the shortcut keycode and check if the user data byte is set to 0 (default)
        -- The user data byte check is to prevent the event handler from triggering itself (SEE PressKey FUNCTION ABOVE)
        -- I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I cant find it

        event:setType(hs.eventtap.event.types.nullEvent)  -- Null the keypress event
        -- Overrides the keypress, remove if you don't want the original keypresses to be overridden
        -- I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I cant find it
        
        keyDownCount = keyDownCount + 1 -- Add one to keypress counter

        if CheckKeyDownCountTimer:running() then -- If the max key press gap timer is running stop it (NOTE: Stopping and starting it also resets it)
            CheckKeyDownCountTimer:stop() 
        end

        if keyDownCount < keyMaxPressCount then -- If keypress counter is less then the max number of keypresses restart the max key press gap timer (NOTE: Stopping and starting it also resets it)
            CheckKeyDownCountTimer:start() 
        else -- Alternativly, if the keypress counter is greater than or equal to the max number of keypresses run the CheckKeyDownCount function 
            CheckKeyDownCount()
        end            
    end
    return false -- Ends the anonymous function by returning false, not sure if this is really necessary but it's what other people seem to do 
end)

multipressBtnShortcuts:start() -- Starts the keydown event handler
```